# AngularJs app.config service provider

Tags: angularjs

In my **app.config** i'm able to retrieve the login from my UserProvider service :

```
var login = "";
UserProvider.$get().getUser()
            .then(function (data) {
                login = data;
            });
```

But how i can retrieve this login outside of the "**.then**" function and do a check with it :

```
if (login == "admin") {

$stateProvider         
            .state('admin', {
                url: '/admin',
                templateUrl: 'app/admin.html',
                controller: 'adminCtrl'
            })

else {
 .state('guest', {
                url: '/guest',
                templateUrl: 'app/guest.html',
                controller: 'guestCtrl'
            })

}
```

Also when i want to display the login in my index.html in the navbar doing this :

```
  .state('/', {
               url: '/',
              templateUrl: 'index.html',
             controller: 'userCtrl',
              resolve: {
               login: function () {
                   return login;
               }
           }
             })
```

I have this error : **Tried to Load Angular More Than Once**.

Thanks for your help

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: You are using Angular in a very bad way, **$get** is a private method that $provide uses for instancing the service released from the provider recipe. Don't use it before the **angular runtime phase**...

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the login name in my app.config and so far i only found the method .$get to do it. Do you have an other better suggestion ? In summary i want to show templates/controller according to the login

Comment: Tarun Dugar : i'm trying to get the user name in app.config and then display templates/controller according to that username. The user name is     sent by my UserService that return a promise after an $http.get (serUrl + "getUSername")

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not rely on configurations.

**Configurations** itself are **STATIC** data and should not be changed at most of cases. Much better approach is **redirect** user upon realizing he is not and **admin** account etc.

You need to create both routes separately and add to your main (top) route `resolveFunction()` function that will acquire with `$http.get()` from your back-end.

At least as soon as you loaded your main controller you will be informed and ready to translate route to sub-state of application (*admin* or *guest* state as sub-modules of main application).

Comment: That's a good start. But let say i have 10 routes configured for the admin and 2 routes  for the guest. I should then do a check in all of thoses 12 controllers in the routes and see if it's an admin or not ? That why i need to find a way to get the user in my app.config and show the routes according to the account

Comment: You have `$stateChangeStart` to predict users next step and redirect him if he is lack of access. At least I've created `runConfig.js` as configuration of whole application to track it's state and manage users accesses and passes.